# Wieso ist die Bezeichnung »scharfes s« ausgerechnet dort verbreitet, wo es kein stimmhaftes s gibt?

Tags: regional, terminology, eszett

Die Bezeichnung *scharfes s* für das Eszett orientiert sich anscheinend (und auch [hiernach](http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/runde-7/f05d/)) an dessen Aussprache: *ß* wird immer stimmlos ausgesprochen, wogegen das normale *s* sowohl stimmlos als auch stimmhaft sein kann – zumindest in norddeutscher Aussprache. In süddeutscher Aussprache sind hingegen alle s-Laute stimmlos bzw. scharf (siehe z. B. [Wikipedia über die österreichische Aussprache](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%96sterreichisches_Deutsch#.C3.96sterreichische_Aussprache_und_das_Lautsystem)).

Interessanterweise ist die Bezeichnung *scharfes s* vor allem im süddeutschen Sprachraum verbreitet (siehe z. B. den [Atlas der deutschen Alltagssprache](http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/runde-7/f05d/)).

Wie kam es zu dieser scheinbar gegenläufigen Verteilung von Aussprache und Terminologie?

Comment: Die Opposition ist ja nicht unbedingt aufgehoben; auch ein [s​ˑ] etwa könnte durchaus als scharf wahrgenommen werden, oder zumindest als schärfer im Vergleich zu einem [s]. – Zweiter Ansatz: Gerade in Gegenden, wo die Opposition von [d] und [t] nicht mehr besteht, wird Schülern beigebracht, zwischen einem „harten _d_“ (Schreibung _t_) und einem „weichen _d_“ (Schreibung _d_) zu unterscheiden.

Comment: Interessant finde ich in dem Zusammenhang, dass das »Gegenstück« zum scharfen S nicht das »weiche« oder »stumpfe« S sondern das »normale S« ist.

Comment: Spannende Frage! Als Schwabe in Berlin habe ich beim Diktieren von "scharfes s" so viele Rückfragen bekommen, dass ich inzwischen auch Eszett sage.

Comment: @Jan: Womit wir bei den didaktischen Nachteilen der Bezeichnung *scharfes s* wären …

Comment: Ich koennte mir vorstellen, dass chirlu die Ursache genau richtig erkannt hat.

Comment: Standardsprachlich spricht man in _Wer in Bu**ss**en oder Bu**tz**en Frauen an die Bu**s**en fasst, muss mit Bu**ß**en rechnen_ die markierten S-Laute stimmlos, stimmlos, stimmhaft und stimmlos. Ich dachte, das geschehe im südlichen Sprachraum ebenso, obwohl dort _sechs_ und _Sex_ homophon sind, nämlich beide am Anfang stimmhaft.

Comment: Mal eine andere Sichweise: wenn man z.B, in Bayern "Eszett" diktiert werden die meisten Leute dort eher "sz" als "ß" aufschreiben ("Es Zett") -> die Bezeichnung "scharfes S" ist lautlich eindeutig dem Zeichen zuweisbar, was bei "Eszett" nicht unbedingt gegeben sein muss.

Comment: Zusätzliche Anmerkung: Ich bin kein Experte für Österreichisch, aber im Bairischen gibt es sehr wohl ein stimmhaftes s (z.B. "Wiesn") - auch wenn es zugegebenermaßen nicht so häufig auftritt. Im Fränkischen ist das stimmhafte s schon deutlich häufiger, aber auch in den Gegenden ist die Bezeichnung "scharfes s" geläufig.

Comment: @Crissov: "im südlichen Sprachraum ebenso, obwohl dort *sechs* und *Sex* homophon sind, nämlich beide am Anfang stimmhaft." - sind sie im südlichen Sprachraum nicht eher beide am Anfang stimmlos (wenn auch dennoch nicht homophon)?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Äh ja, sicher /s-/, steht ja auch schon in der Frage so (inkl. WP-Link). Süddeutsch ausgesprochen sind die beiden Wörter mindestens für norddeutsche Hörer homophon. Es gibt allerdings auch andere, nördliche Mundarten, in denen man keinen Unterschied hört, dann allerdings /z-/.

Comment: @Crissov: »Wer in /busn/ oder /butsn/ Frauen an die /bu:sn/ fasst, muss mit /bu:sn/ rechnen« – stimmlos, stimmloses Affrikat, stimmlos, stimmlos. Aussprache aus Südwestbayern. Außerdem, wie Mapper sagt: /seks/ ist sowohl *sechs* als auch *Sex*.

Comment: @hoffmale Bei uns wird die Wiesn stimmlos ausgesprochen …

Comment: @Jan: Wollt ihr daraus vielleicht eine eigene Frage machen?

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Ich persönlich hab keinen Bedarf an einer solchen Frage, aber ich würde mich einer Antwort nicht verweigern ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ein paar Mutmassungen:

1. Die deutschen Fortis- und Lenis-Laute wurden traditionell – mindestens bis ins frühe 20. Jahrhundert und in der Dialektologie noch bedeutend länger – als *scharfe* (bzw. *harte*) und *weiche* (bzw. *sanfte* oder *gelinde*) Laute bezeichnet. Heute werden sie hingegen eher als *stimmlose* und *stimmhafte* Laute bezeichnet. Zum einen dürfte dies damit zu tun haben, dass sie von Siebs so beschrieben worden sind, zum anderen damit, dass sich inzwischen die IPA-Lautschrift durchgesetzt hat, wo sie nach französischem Vorbild als stimmlose und stimmhafte Laute definiert sind.

   Die Bezeichnungen *stimmlos* und *stimmhaft* sind jedoch fürs Deutsche eher ungeeignet. In der norddeutschen Aussprache, die mit der Dominanz Preussens vorbildlich geworden ist und die Siebs zum Vorbild genommen hat, sind die Lenis-Laute zwar oft stimmhaft. Sie sind es aber nicht immer. Stimmhaftigkeit ist zwar eine hinreichende Bedingung für Lenis-Laute, aber nicht eine notwendige, denn sie können auch im Norddeutschen stimmlos auftreten – insbesondere nach anderen stimmlosen Lauten, wie beispielsweise beim *s* im Wort *Absicht*. Dementsprechend ist die Stimmlosigkeit weder eine notwendige noch eine hinreichende Bedingung für einen Fortis-Laut. Ausserhalb des Norddeutschen sind die Lenis-Laute sowieso stimmlos. Trotzdem unterscheiden sie sich von den Fortis-Lauten.

   Ausserhalb des Norddeutschen trifft es also zu, dass «alle s-Laute stimmlos» sind. Die Behauptung, ausserhalb des Norddeutschen wären alle s-Laute scharf, ist aber völlig falsch. Nur die scharfen s-Laute sind scharf. Sie unterscheiden sich von den weichen s-Lauten, die nicht scharf sind, sondern weich. Innerhalb des Norddeutschen sind die weichen s-Laute oft stimmhaft, aber nicht immer.

   Also ist die Bezeichnung *scharfes s* für den Laut /s/ sowohl traditioneller als auch zutreffender denn die Bezeichnung *stimmloses s*. Es ist naheliegend, die traditionelle Bezeichnung *scharfes s* auf den Buchstaben ⟨ß⟩ zu übertragen, denn er entspricht immer dem scharfen s-Laut /s/.
2. Vermutlich ist die Bezeichnung *Eszett* die ältere. In der Fraktur, aus der das Zeichen stammt, fügt sich das Zeichen bekanntlich in eine Reihe von nicht-trennbaren Ligaturen: *ch, ck, ſt, tz* und eben auch *ſz*. In der nationalistischen Aufbruchstimmung nach der Erschaffung des preussisch-deutschen Kaiserreichs wurde eine (nach heutigen Massstäben äusserst radikale) Reform der deutschen Rechtschreibung in Angriff genommen. Im Rahmen dieser Reform wurde die Fraktur-Ligatur *ſz* als *ß* in die Antiqua übertragen. Vorher gab es in der Antiqua kein *ß*, und man schrieb einfach *ss* (oder allenfalls *ſs*). Das *ſz* existierte nur in der Fraktur.

   Der Name *Es-Zett* für das *ſz* der Fraktur ist naheliegend – genauso wie der Name *Te-Zett* für das *tz* oder der Name *Ce-Ha* für das *ch*.
3. Laut [Bezeichnung “ß” « atlas-alltagssprache](http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/runde-7/f05d/) decken sich die Gebiete, wo die Bezeichnungen *Eszett* oder *scharfes S* verwendet werden, relativ gut mit den Ländergrenzen. Ausgenommen ist nur Nordrhein-Westfalen, wo beide Bezeichnungen vorkommen. Dies legt die Vermutung nahe, dass die jeweils verwendeten Lehrmittel eine Rolle spielen.

   Sehr spekulativ: Vielleicht wurde bei der Einführung des neuen Buchstabens *ß* die neue Bezeichnung *scharfes S* überall eingeführt ausser in Preussen? Das *Eszett*-Gebiet deckt sich einigermassen mit den früheren Ausmassen Preussens.